# Why does running this query with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE cause it to fail?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql, ora-00911

I am writing a PL/SQL procedure that needs to to dynamically generate some queries, one of which involves creating a temporary table using results from a query taken as a parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sqlout(query IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tab AS (' || query || ');';
END;
```

It compiles correctly, but even with very simple queries such as with:

```
BEGIN
    sqlout('SELECT * FROM DUAL');
END;
```

IT throws `ORA-00911: invalid character`. If I run the created query manually it runs correctly. At this point I am able to determine what is causing the problem.

Comment: I hope that proc isn't being run in the normal course of events by your application... dynamic DDL is only really appropriate for admin scripts (e.g. setting up a new environment).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try to lose the ";" from inside the string that you Execute Immediate.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tab AS (' || query || ')';
```